# Unknown OS type Linux.5.0.0-15-generic

Tags: gnome-terminal, 19.04

Recently I have upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 19.04. After the completion of the upgrade, I get the following error when I open the terminal

```
Warning: unknown OS type Linux.5.0.0-15-generic
```

Although this is not affecting me from doing work using the terminal, I would like to know why this warning shows.

The output of a few commands:

`cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="19.04 (Disco Dingo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 19.04"
VERSION_ID="19.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=disco
UBUNTU_CODENAME=disco
```

`hostnamectl`

```
   Static hostname: envy
   Icon name: computer-laptop
   Chassis: laptop
   Machine ID: 404b7c62fbba444287a5256a4604788c
   Boot ID: 9a3d75b8a927419d87c4957335ab2a1e
   Operating System: Ubuntu 19.04
   Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-15-generic
   Architecture: x86-64
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
```

`uname -r`

`5.0.0-15-generic`

Comment: Could you give us some more context? Does this happen before `bash` gives you the prompt? Did you check your rc files like `.bashrc` to locate the cause?

Comment: Do the commands `cat /etc/os-release`,
`lsb_release -a`,
`hostnamectl`, and 
`uname -r` print the correct (expected) info?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Yes, all these commands print the correct info corresponding to Ubuntu 19.04. ```hostnamectl``` prints  ```Operating System: Ubuntu 19.04``` ```Kernel: Linux 5.0.0-15-generic```  & ```Architecture: x86-64```

Comment: I would suggest trying to find which initialization script throws this warning. Is it a script in your current user or in the system? Try to create a **new** user and test if the same message is displayed. If yes, then something in the system scripts (under /etc/..); if no something under your user causes it.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli For a **new** user, no such warning is printed.

Comment: Look at "dot" files under your home directory: .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .bash_aliases, etc. etc.

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar  @FedonKadifeli The problem was in the `.bashrc` file. Located the issue with an environment. Removed the entry of that particular environment from the `.bashrc` and there is no warning.